# How to listen to flutter application console output?

Tags: flutter, dart, logging

I have different libraries added to my flutter application. I'm implementing a feature in the application where whenever an error or message is printed to the console from any library or error message, I want to send that error or message string to the server.

How can I listen to console in flutter programmatically so whenever a string is printed to the console I can capture it to send it to the server later?

Answer (score 6):

**One possible solution that I can think of is to intercept `print()` method and then you can get all the values whenever the `print()` method is called in the current zone.**

After intercepting the value, you can save it to a file or so whatever you want to. I don't know if it's the most suitable way to do it.

```
  void main() {
  runZoned(() {
    // Ends up printing: "Intercepted: in zone".
    runApp(MyApp());
  }, zoneSpecification: new ZoneSpecification(
      print: (Zone self, ZoneDelegate parent, Zone zone, String line) {
    parent.print(zone, "Intercepted: $line");
    //save to a file or do whatever you want
  }));
}
```